# querySelectorAll shim for non-IE browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Every shim I have seen for this function has used the IE-only CSS `expression` trick. While there's no denying it's effective, it's made useless if the browser is not IE and doesn't support `querySelectorAll` either.

jQuery is out of the question, since I don't want to get a whole framework just to shim one tiny little function. So I went and wrote my own. I'd like to submit it for review, which may include optimisations.

Please note that this is not a complete shim, only enough for what is frequently used:

- tag name
- id
- class name
- attribute, presence and exact value match
- descendant combinator
- child combinator

The code:

```
if( typeof document.querySelector == "undefined") {
    document.querySelectorAll = function(sel) {
        var sels = sel.split(","),
            run = function(node,selector) {
                var sel = selector.split(/[ >]+/), com = selector.match(/[ >]+/g) || [], s, c, ret = [node], nodes, l, i, subs, m, j, check, x, w, ok,
                    as;
                com.unshift(" ");
                while(s = sel.shift()) {
                    c = com.shift();
                    if( c) c = c.replace(/^ +| +$/g,"");
                    nodes = ret.slice(0);
                    ret = [];
                    l = nodes.length;
                    subs = s.match(/[#.[]?[a-z_-]+(?:='[^']+'|="[^"]+")?]?/gi);
                    m = subs.length;
                    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
                        if( subs[0].charAt(0) == "#") ret = [document.getElementById(subs[0].substr(1))];
                        else {
                            check = c == ">" ? nodes[i].children : nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("*");
                            if( !check) continue;
                            w = check.length;
                            for( x=0; x<w; x++) {
                                ok = true;
                                for( j=0; j<m; j++) {
                                    switch(subs[j].charAt(0)) {
                                    case ".":
                                        if( !check[x].className.match(new RegExp("\\b"+subs[j].substr(1)+"\\b"))) ok = false;
                                        break;
                                    case "[":
                                        as = subs[j].substr(1,subs[j].length-2).split("=");
                                        if( !check[x].getAttribute(as[0])) ok = false;
                                        else if( as[1]) {
                                            as[1] = as[1].replace(/^['"]|['"]$/g,"");
                                            if( check[x].getAttribute(as[0]) != as[1]) ok = false;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        if( check[x].tagName.toLowerCase() != subs[j].toLowerCase()) ok = false;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    if( !ok) break;
                                }
                                if( ok) ret.push(check[x]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return ret;
            }, l = sels.length, i, ret = [], tmp, m, j;
        for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
            tmp = run(this,sels[i]);
            m = tmp.length;
            for( j=0; j<m; j++) {
                ret.push(tmp[j]);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    };
    document.querySelector = function(sel) {
        var ret = this.querySelectorAll(sel);
        if( ret.length > 0) return ret[0];
        else return null;
    };
    if( typeof HTMLElement != "undefined") {
        HTMLElement.prototype.querySelector = document.querySelector;
        HTMLElement.prototype.querySelectorAll = document.querySelectorAll;
    }
    else {
        dommods_extend.push(function() {
            var a = document.getElementsByTagName("*"), l = a.length, i;
            for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
                a[i].querySelector = document.querySelector;
                a[i].querySelectorAll = document.querySelectorAll;
            }
        });
        // dommods_extend is an array of functions that are run whenever the DOM is updated,
        // to apply changes such as auto-resizing textareas, default value for <select> and so on.
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick note: is it really necessary to `querySelectorAll` when you just want to `querySelector`? It seems highly inefficient.

Comment: Maybe you should have `querySelectorAll` and `querySelector` call a single function taking a last argument (a flag saying whether to take more than one result or not).

Comment: And the last suggestion: what about separating your code into multiple functions? It'd allow you to have less nesting than you currently have (so, more readability).

Comment: You could take a look at [Sizzle's source](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js). It's the DOM selector engine used in jQuery (Not the entire jQuery library).

Comment: For something as complex as this, it is probably a good idea to write some tests.

Comment: Are you taking into account that commas may be present besides separating multiple selectors? E.g. `a[href="/foo?bar=1,2,4"]`.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté No, I'm not, since I know they won't be anywhere I use them. Good point, though.

Comment: @Kolink: Do you have this up on Github or somewhere, or would you mind if I forked it? Because I think it's a worthwhile concept, and it might be useful on a future project I might work on.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Please feel free to copy, paste, edit, whatever you like with this code. I won't provide support for it though, so make sure you understand its limitations.

Comment: @Kolink: Excellent. I'll post here if I make any changes to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overal

I am not sure which non IE-browser doesn't support querySelectorAll. Regardless, the code seems very performant, if a little Golfic ( reminds me of code golf ).

### Nitpickings

If you wish this source to be maintained / debugged /reviewed by others, there are some things you can change to make that easier:

- Declare unassigned variables last. It is easier on the eyes to know when to stop reading that long var line.
- I am all for Spartan coding, but w,m,c (which is not a character!), l etc. just make for unmaintainable code.
- Make your regex's constants with a meaningful name, it will make your code easier to understand.
- Use new lines after the `if` condition
- if/else branches should either both have curly braces, or both not have curly braces, dont mix
- You could use `Array.concat` here:

> ```
> //As is
> for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
>     tmp = run(this,sels[i]);
>     m = tmp.length;
>     for( j=0; j<m; j++) {
>         ret.push(tmp[j]);
>     }
> }
> //Replacement proposal
> for( i=0; i<l; i++)
>   ret.push( run(this,sels[i])  );
> ```

- You could use a trinary here :

> ```
> //As is 
> if( ret.length > 0) return ret[0];
> else return null
> //Replacement proposal
> return ret.length?ret[0]:null;
> ```

### Finally

It is considered bad practice to shim in incomplete implementations, if you want to add to the HTMLElement prototype, use your own names to remove any confusion. `HTMLElement.prototype.darkQuerySelector` sounds so much better anyway ;)

Comment: If nothing else, +1 for `darkQuerySelector` XD I've stopped supporting IE7 in new projects anyways, but thanks for your input!